# Microsoft Bot Framework channel integration: more endpoints?

Tags: rest, api, botframework, chatbot

I'm using Microsoft Bot Framework using the channel registration product and the REST API. I have setup the "messaging endpoint" and everything works fine for sending and receiving messages.

But I don't just want to send/receive messages. Something as simple as setting up a welcome message seems impossible because my endpoint receives nothing other than messaging events (when the bot is in the channel / conversation.)

Is there something I have missed?

I would like to setup several endpoints, or use the same, whatever, to listen to other types of events.

Comment: please show the code for your MessagesController.

Comment: sorry but your question is unclear. If your problem is about sending a welcome message to users, please add more details about the channel you are using, add your MessagesController code, etc. If it's something else, edit your question

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here exactly and how is it a coding problem? Please share your code. What did you try, what worked? What didn't work?

Comment: There is no code to share. The issue is that when setting up MBF using the "channel" integration product, it seems like the only available endpoint (that receives HTTP requests from MBF) I am able to set up only listens to messages received by the bot. This is set up directly in the MBF console. I am wondering if there is an API or configuration I have missed, that would allow me to receive event types other than messaging events.

Comment: Note that this is using the REST API (or websocket) only, NOT using the node.js SDK for instance.

Comment: To clarify further..

When a bot receives a message from a user, MBF sends an HTTP request to a "messaging endpoint" that one must configure in the console panel. From there, my client can parse the request body, which is basically messaging information, and respond accordingly.

However, ONLY messaging events are received, not other types of events such as a new user joining the channel. I am interested in receiving requests for such events too.

Comment: When a user adds a contact, some channels send a ContactRelationUpdate event.  Some channels send a ConversationUpdate event when a user is added or removed from a conversation. These all come in on the same MessagingEndpoint, but the type of the activity/message is different.

Comment: I never receive these requests. Maybe I need to set up another service on MBF, something other than the channel service. It is a little confusing, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement in the MessageController something like these:
Pay attention in the else if. The funcition in the controller is HandleSystemMessage.

else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {

```
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
            IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
            var cliente = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());

            if (update.MembersAdded != null && update.MembersAdded.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var member in update.MembersAdded)
                {
                    if(member.Id != message.Recipient.Id)
                    {
                        //var username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                        var username = message.From.Name;
                        var reply = message.CreateReply();
                        //string dir = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Images" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "cajamar.png";
                        string dir = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "Images" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "cajamar.png";

                        reply.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(
                                contentUrl: dir,
                                contentType: "image/png",
                                name: "cajamar.png"
                            ));
                        reply.Text = $"Bienvenido {username} al ChatBot de convenios:";
                        cliente.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(reply);
                        //var reply = message.CreateReply();

                        //reply.Text = $"El directorio base es: {HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath}";
                        //cliente.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Jorge, but I am not using the node SDK (nor any of their SDKs).